# Site shows white page

Tags: 7, installation

I've just cloned a full functioning website with its database.

But on localhost:

- The index page shows a white page
- When I go to the login page, it shows a login form with basic HTML, without CSS styles, and no template.
- When I try to log in, it redirects me to https://localhost/sitename/user/admin, which I am not allowed to access.
- I've tried to compare another page just now and it isn't white, but it doesn't show what it needs to show too. It shows the following code.

  ```
  [t001_01_main.tpl.php] var addthis_config = addthis_config||{}; addthis_config.ui_email_note = 'verbind: test setting E-mail text'; */?>
  ```

  I'm running the localhost on a Macbook Pro without MAMP. Other Drupal installations work fine.

I have tried putting the following code, but it gives the same result.

```
error_reporting(-1);  // Have PHP complain about absolutely everything 
$conf['error_level'] = 2;  // Show all messages on your screen, 2 = ERROR_REPORTING_DISPLAY_ALL.
 ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);  // These lines just give you content on WSOD pages.
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

I've looked into WPOD, but I can't access anything on the site. In /etc/apache2 there isn't any error.log file.

The problem isn't with one page; the user page is plain HTML and when logging in my site keeps redirecting to https:// (like said in the second paragraph). So many solutions found about WPOD can't be tried because I can't login.

The Drupal version of this project is 7.36, php version of my localhost is 5.6.19

- I've tried updating the drupal version to 7.51
- I've tried using php 5.4 (oldest version I have installed)
- There are no new errors in the watchdog table

Live site works like a charm , other local websites that I've imported to localhost allso work

Comment: You are probably suffering from WSOD - White Screen of Death. We'll need more details to debug it. Did you copy the .htaccess file when you moved the site? It's invisible so sometimes gets missed - https://www.drupal.org/node/158043

Comment: @MarkConroy, the .htaccess file was included in when I cloned the site.
 I've already tried to replace the .htaccess file with one of a clean drupal download but it didn't make any difference. What information do you need :)

Comment: Did you edit the sites/default/settings.php to match your local database name and password, after cloning the site?

Comment: @TBJ , yess i've imported the db with sequel pro, like I always do. It has always worked. Even now wit a new site that I'm working on it works.
It's just that one that doesn't

Comment: If you are using memcache you can try to disable that module (before cloning) and also comment out everything that is related to memcache in settings.php. I had this WSOD problem some time ago, and in my case it was memcache that caused the headache.

Comment: @TBJ thanks for the suggestion, I didn't find a module called memcache neither did I find anything in the settings.php of memcache. :/

Comment: Looks like you _might_ have an issue with your add_this module in Drupal. Judging by your error.

Comment: @MarkConroy Thank you for your answer. Looking for the addthis module on the site I noticed that there wasn't a module named addthis. In the html.tpl.php file there is a script loaded from addthis.com. ‘//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-554cae2b‌​0cb270c0‘. But it does not really say error on the page it's more like it's printing the php in the template

Comment: It seems that the php version of the project is way older than the php version I'm using

Comment: a) You mention that your site is on https://localhost/sitename/. Have you tried setting `RewriteBase /sitename` in .htaccess? This makes sense if your `SiteName` is configured as `localhost` on your virtualhost config. b) When you go to the login page, you mention the page displays but without any styling, what does it say on the "Network" tab of your console for the CSS file requests? If it's 404, check the path to the CSS.  If it doesn't include /sitename on the basepath, then a) "should" be able to resolve this? Let me know.

Comment: @Beebee, Thank you for your respons. My site isn't configured in my virtual host because it stopped working after updating to  macOS sierra (Fixed apache and mysql but can't seem to fix virtual host). But that's another issue. I've managed to sign in by deleting a redirect to `https://` in the index.php . 
But I've noticed that the file is written in a old version of php (using `<?` instead of `<?php` and closing every module file with `?>`). So I'm now trying to adjust the code

Comment: Core index.php shouldn't be modified at all. Sounds like you have deeper fundamental problems with that site.